# Query between two relative dates, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this function but I'd like the user to be able to search between 1 and 2 months back, or 6 and 19 months, or whatever.

```
$query =     
"SELECT * FROM reports 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$dateMax." MONTH)"
```

I cannot find any documentation about changing the NOW function into a relative date. Any help would be appreciated.

Something like:

```
$query =     
"SELECT * FROM reports 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW() - ".$dateMin." MONTH, INTERVAL ".$dateMax." MONTH)"
```

would be really great, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "
SELECT
  *
FROM
  reports
WHERE
  date BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL $dateMin MONTH) AND (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL $dateMax MONTH);
";
```

Another option would be a date instead of CURRENT_DATE:

```
  date BETWEEN ('2009-08-01' - INTERVAL $dateMin MONTH) AND ('2008-08-01' - INTERVAL $dateMax MONTH);
```